# Jedis waitForLock Time Limit or Override

Tags: java, spring, jedis, spring-data-redis

In my investigation of an issue I am having with Jedis getting resources from Redis, I discovered that Spring Data Redis has a method called waitForLock that goes into interation of Thread.sleep when there is a cache lock key name in Redis.
This iteration goes on till the cache lock key is out of Redis so it may be a very long time (like 27 minutes in my case).

Is there a config that exists for me to override this behaviour, that is, creating a limit for which Spring Data Redis will check this lock key before throwing exception.

Or is there another way around it other than config settings.

Comment: please vote for [DATAREDIS-399](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREDIS-399)